# Selective get in cassandra faster than normal get?

Tags: php, database, nosql, cassandra, phpcassa

I'd like to know if this:

```
$column_family->get('row_key', $columns=array('name1', 'name2'));
```

Is faster then the more flexible get i now use:

```
$column_family->get('row_key');
```

Method 1 is harder to implement of course but will it give less load/bandwidth/delay?

Comment: Based on the knowlegde of MySQL; `"SELECT field FROM table"` is faster than `"SELECT * FROM table"`, so my guess would be that a more selective get is faster. Although you can question yourself if it's noticeable on small datasets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one is faster, especially if you work with large tables that contain plenty of columns.

Even you have just two columns called `name1` and `name2`, specifying their names should avoid extracting column names from table structure on MySQL side. So it should be faster than using `*` selector.

However, test your results using **[microtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)** in PHP against large tables and you'll see what I'm talking about. Of course, if you have 20+ columns in table and you want to extract them all it's easier to put `*` than listing all those column-names but in terms of speed, listing columns is bit quicker.

The best way to check out this conclusion, is to test it by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Cassandra is not mysql so it will come as no surprise that some things are different there. :)

In this case, Cassandra's sparse-row storage model means that for *small* numbers of columns the full-row version will be faster because Cassandra doesn't need to deserialize and check its row-level column entries.

Of course for larger numbers of columns the extra work of deserializing more than you need will dominate again.

Bottom line: worrying about this is almost certainly premature optimization. When it's not, test.